# How to Get data-* attributes when web scraping using python requests (Python Requests Creating Some Issues)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, html-parsing, hidden

How can I get the value of data-d1-value when I am using requests library of python?

The request.get(URL) function is itself not giving the data-* attributes in the div which are present in the original webpage.

The web page is as follows:

```
<div id="test1" class="class1" data-d1-value="150">
180
</div>
```

The code I am using is :

```
req = request.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
d1_value = soup.find('div', {'class':"class1"})
print(d1_value)
```

The result I get is:

```
<div id="test1" class="class1">
180
</div>
```

When I debug this, I found that request.get(URL) is not returning the full div but only the id and class and not data-* attributes.

How should I modify to get the full value?

For better example:
For my case the URL is:
https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/oil-drillingexploration/oilnaturalgascorporation/ONG

And the Information of variable:
The DIV CLASS is : class="inprice1 nsecp" and The value of data-numberanimate-value is what I am trying to fetch

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for adding information, but what is the url or the response from the request?  Just in case read this please: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Comment: So, if there is no data attribute in the response, it might be that the website serves dynamic content, that requests could not get. To check this, please provide the url, you are requesting.

Comment: Thanks I'll read the link you just shared:
For my case the link is:
https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/oil-drillingexploration/oilnaturalgascorporation/ONG
And the value I am trying to get is :
The DIV CLASS is : class="inprice1 nsecp" and The value of data-numberanimate-value is what I am trying to fetch

Comment: Thanks for improving looks much better and detailed, take a look at me edit, based on this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Website response differs in case of requesting it - In your case using requests the value you are looking for is served in this way:

```
<div class="inprice1 nsecp" id="nsecp" rel="92.75">92.75</div>
```

So you can get it from the `rel` or from the `text`:

```
soup.find('div', {'class':"inprice1"})['rel']
soup.find('div', {'class':"inprice1"}).get_text()
```

**Example**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/oil-drillingexploration/oilnaturalgascorporation/ONG')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

print('rel: '+soup.find('div', {'class':"inprice1"})['rel'])
print('text :'+soup.find('div', {'class':"inprice1"}).get_text())
```

**Output**

```
rel: 92.75
text: 92.75
```

### To get a response that display the source as you inspect it, you have to try selenium

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/oil-drillingexploration/oilnaturalgascorporation/ONG"

driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
print(soup.find('div', class_='inprice1 nsecp')['data-numberanimate-value'])
driver.close()
```

---

To get the attribute value just add `['data-d1-value']` to your `find()`

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div id="test1" class="class1" data-d1-value="150">
180
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
d1_value = soup.find('div', {'class':"class1"})['data-d1-value']
print(d1_value)
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, but the request.get(URL) function itself doesn't give the data attributes, it is just returning: <div id="test1" class="class1"> 180 </div>

Comment: @Xavier: Then you should improve your question and add this information, so that everybody knows and can help, please. Thanks

Comment: I have done that, hope that clears some doubts.

Comment: Take a look at my edit, hope this will help to understand and decide wich way you will go.

Answer (score 0):

you are seeing this issue, because you didn't retrieve all of the other attributes which we're defined on the DIV.

The below code will retrieve all of the custom attributes which we're defined on the div as well

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '<div id="test1" class="class1" data-d1-value="150">180</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

attributes_dictionary = soup.find('div',{'class':"class1"}).attrs
print(attributes_dictionary)
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, but the request.get(URL) function itself doesn't give the data attributes, it is just returning:
<div id="test1" class="class1">
180
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from HTML or you just can do it scraping the API

This is an example:

Website is: [Money Control](https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/oil-drillingexploration/oilnaturalgascorporation/ONG)

If you going to developer tools into your browser, and select Network, you can see the requests that are doing the website:

[See image](https://fotos.subefotos.com/f7ae99913ae3754d2998a580b1b002e0o.png)

You can see that in headers, appear URL from API: [priceapi.moneycontrol.com](https://priceapi.moneycontrol.com/pricefeed/nse/equitycash/ONG).

This is a strange case, because the API is open... and usually it isn't.

You can access to price:

Imagine that you save JSON data into a variable called 'json', you can access it with:

```
json.data.pricecurrent
```